# jwplayer works on desktop but not on all mobile, why?

Tags: javascript, android, css, html

this is how I initialize it:

```
autostart:true
file:"//strlb.nava.hu/lbs/navahus/_definst_/amlst:2334206?type=m3u&sessid=U2FsdGVkX1%2BT8isbmDU7Vz56rK8KVCo2xKgOLwwR5JUSq5m5GfKrL4HM%2FrbhwdyJJ0gyyK0X6%2FrAbTjfnsBAqg%3D%3D_2"
height:360
id:"videoPlayer"
preload:"metadata"
primary:"html5"
type:"hls"
width:640
```

it works on desktop, and on android with chrome. But on desktop, if I switch chrome to mobile view, it say "error loading player: no playable sources found"

Answer (score 0):

allright guys, it looks I solved it out: it needs extra parameters:

```
androidhls => false,
hlsjsdefault => true
```